# Как проверить подключение к БД в MODx revo

Tags: php, modx, redbeanphp

Как проверить подключение к удаленной БД на MODx revo, если подключаюсь через redbean.php (ORM). Почему возник вопрос: БД, к которой подключаюсь, в PHPMyAdmin стоит PHP расширение mysqli, а redbean подключает через команду mysql.
Так как же мне проверить подключился я к БД или нет?

Answer (score 0):

Так как вопрос состоит из двух частей, отвечать буду по очереди.

1) Как проверить подключение. Если не выпало никаких ошибок - подключение удалось. Попробуйте выполнить какой-нибудь запрос, к примеру на выборку var_dump(R::queryAll('SELECT * FROM table'));

2) И расширение mysql, и расширение mysqli выполняют примерно одинаковую функцию. Расширение mysql признано устаревшим и было [удалено](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php) в PHP версии 7.